El valor de name solo se imprime una vez en modal en Vue.js cuando debería mostrar diferentes valores para cada instancia
Estoy trabajando con Vue.js y tengo un componente padre que renderiza un modal utilizando un v-for. El modal debería mostrar información diferente basada en los datos que recibe. Sin embargo, el valor de name solo se imprime una vez y no imprime los demas valores, cuando no lo trabajo como modal en el componente hijo, si me muestran los todos los valores, pero cuando es modal solo se muestra uno.
Este es mi componente padre:
 <template>
      <div
        v-for="(requestDocument, index) in documentsCanje.slice(0, 3)"
        :key="requestDocument.id"
        class="tw-w-full"
      >
        <ModalDocumentsCanje
          :visible="visibleModals[index]"
          @update:visible="visibleModals[index] = $event"
          @confirm="updateStatusConfirmed"
          :url="uploadUrl"
          :csrf="csrfToken"
          :documents="documentsCanje"
          :name="requestDocument.name"
          :accept="requestDocument.exts"
          :disabled="false"
        />
      </div>
    </template>

Este es mi componete hijo :
   <template>
     <div v-if="true" class="modal-overlay">
       <div class="modal-content">
         
         <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
         <button @click="confirm">Confirmar</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </template>
   
   
   <style scoped>
   .modal-overlay {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }
   .modal-content {
     background: white;
     padding: 20px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: 80%;
     max-width: 500px;
   }
   </style>


aca hay algo raro.. porque tenes un modal dentro de un form.. si es modal, se muestar una solo... como haces para mostrar mas de uno??? no deberia ser un solo modal, y pasarle los parametros que queres???
